# How configure the pool size of @MessageDriven without using annotation?

Tags: configuration, pool, message-driven-bean, jboss7.x

We have a *unique* EAR file and we would like to deploy it on two distinct servers.

On the first one, we don't want any `MessageDriven` beans to be processed (this server is dedicated to synchronous requests and to produce JMS messages).

On the second one, we want a `MessageDriven` beans pool to listen and process the JMS messages.

**We are on JBoss 7**.0.2 (and we'll move to 7.1.0 thereafter).

The only way I found to configure pool size is through an `@ActivationConfigProperty` with name `maxSession`, but it means the value is hard coded in the class file.

Is there another way, like a configuration in the not-so-well documented `standalone.xml`, that allows us to define the pool size by server?

Answer (score 1):

I meant that you should go to admin console of JBoss Application Server 7+.

This can be done in other servers.

Refer this web page -> [click](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/1.0.7/html/SessionBean_and_MDB_configuration.html)

Comment: Do you refer to the web console of the AS (in which case I checked that but cannot find any way to configure the pool size), or to some online documentation I may have not seen?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid this documentation is not for JBoss7 (which changes all the configuration system), and besides I cannot find any reference to the console in the linked web page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in jboss.xml:
[JBoss docs](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/1.0.7/html/SessionBean_and_MDB_configuration.html)

Comment: Agreed, but there is no longer `jboss.xml` file in JBoss7 (or it is really well hidden).With the standalone.xml thing, all the configuration set is now changed :-/